# Compiling problem - Why doesn't Int work on my age variable?

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXQbM.png)

First program I make after hello world. Firstname, lastname and age. When using String on age, everything works as expected. I was told to use Int on age instead of String, but when I changed to Int and try to compile, I get this error: "cannot find symbol". I guess I have to do something completely different if I want age as an Int. What am I doing wrong?

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Oppgave2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Skriv inn fornavn: ");
    String fornavn = scanner.nextLine();



    System.out.println("Skriv inn etternavn: ");
    String etternavn = scanner.nextLine();



    System.out.println("Skriv inn alder: ");
    int alder = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ditt navn er: " + fornavn + " " + etternavn);
    System.out.println("Din alder er: " + alder);
}
```

}

Comment: `Int` is not a type, that's why you get the "cannot find symbol". Either `int` or `Integer` can be used, but you have to use `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()` since that returns a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` returns a `String`, as said in the [javadoc of Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).
Use `nextInt()` if you want to get and store a int.

Answer (score 0):

In the Scanner class, you use nextInt() when expecting the token to be an integer.

Int alder = scanner.nextInt()

Comment: Your code will still cause a "cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: @f1sh why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Read string using `nextLine` and then convert to int

```
String reply = sc.nextLine();
int alder = Integer.valueOf(reply).intValue;
```